# Apple Watch notifications going to watch or phone intelligently

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-watch

My watch and phone work really well together, if I'm wearing my watch then notifications pop up there first and don't show on my phone. When I take my watch off or when I'm using my phone the notifications appear on my phone.

However on my girlfriends watch the notifications pop up first on her phone, then on her watch a couple of second later, no matter the 'state' of either device. I can't find any setting mismatches. Is there a setting somewhere which causes the behaviour I'm getting?

Comment: Did your girlfriend enable wrist detection?

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the general behaviour of the apple watch. Make sure your apple watch is on your wrist before testing this.

Notification distribution is depend on you are wearing it or not.

Comment: Yep, as I said the notifications on my girlfriends watch seem independent of the "state" of the devices, including if it's being worn or not.